# Add content to WooCommerce My account dashboard main page section

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

Hi I have been searching for how to add items or custom HTML to the main dashboard landing page of the "my account" section of WooCommerce but cant find it. I am adding this in my child theme and all I can find through searches is how to directly edit the `woocommerce_account_content`. Since I want to do this out of my child theme should I user a filter or a hook?

I have tried this:

```
// define the woocommerce_account_content callback 
function action_woocommerce_account_content(  ) { 
    // code here, 
}; 
         
// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_content', 'action_woocommerce_account_content', 10, 0 );
```

But it didnt work when I simply added an echo "hello" as a test. What needs to be changed in order to add custom content to this section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note - There are 2 types of hooks:**

- Filter hooks that always return a (filtered) argument
- Action hooks that use the hook to trigger some code…

**The action hook `woocommerce_account_content` is the right hook to be used** and work on most themes:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_content', 'action_woocommerce_account_content' );
function action_woocommerce_account_content(  ) {
    global $current_user; // The WP_User Object

    echo '<p>' . __("This is an addition…", "woocommerce") . '</p>';
};
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**If it doesn't work** in your case, it's due to your theme (customizations), some other plugin or some other code that you have added yourself…

**First thing to do:** Ask your theme's authors on their support page.

Related: [All threads in StackOverFlow using `woocommerce_account_content` action hook.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=woocommerce_account_content)

Comment: ok thanks but the above code should work as I had it or do I need what you have with the <p> tags?